# Working with localStorage for a dynamic UI in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've gotten far in my simple code, considering I'm barely scathing intermediate JavaScript.

However, I'm working with localStorage for the first time, and all is well, except for the fact that it remembers where I drag the div in my array of Widgets at [0], but anything after [0] isn't remembered.

http://jsfiddle.net/45Mu9/

I Doubt JSFiddle will work with `localStorage`. I hope you can figure out where I made my mistake.

Also, any improvements in efficiency, (don't know any jQuery) are nice to know, but pure JavaScript for now is ideal.

Thank you! Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you dug into the developer console to see if any errors are coming out? Maybe the way you access your array at L:35 is not correct!

Comment: @Rob Thank you! I started there, and went on and fixed it! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Othanan Good to hear so! Would you mind answering your own question so that other users could benefit from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had some mistakes in the way I accessed the array by attempting to use a string.

http://jsfiddle.net/92tV8/

Check for changes in:

```
 loadLocalStorage();
```